# What is the value of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2^{n-1}}{1+a^{2n-1}}, a > 0$

I was considering the use of some power series, but to no end as the denominator of the fraction does no simply after derivation.

Comment: What happend if $0\le a\le 2$?

Comment: yes it does, thank you